# Yammer App Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, yammer

Is there a line of code that bypasses the second app authentication screen where you select Allow or Deny?  I would like our users to automatically be connected to the registered app.

Thanks!

Comment: If your network has office 365 identity enabled, you may consider using the ADAL approach - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2016/07/05/yammer-apis-and-adal-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to bypass that step. If it were possible it would be a security hole.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, is it possible, for paid networks. To be able to do this, your application should use an access token that must be authorized as verified network admin, so it could impersonate user access tokens, take a look at [impersonation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation) on Yammer documentation for more information about this.

Comment: At some point someone has to acquire an OAuth token by going through the browser and authorizing the app. That's probably the reason for the down votes.

Comment: Actually not, using token impersonation avoid this